# Will iOS, jailbroken or not, work on RP Model B?

Tags: operating-systems

I want to purchase a RasberryPi Model B, to explore the programming and robotics capabilities. I was just wondering about iOS and maybe even android, will it work on a Model B?

Answer (score 4):

You won't get iOS to run on the Pi hardware, but you can get Android running with [various levels of usefulness](http://androidpi.wikia.com/wiki/Android_Pi_Wiki).

There's a [Pi blog post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/1700) available. The wiki page (CC-BY-SA license) states:

> CyanogenMOD 9 (based on Android 4.0): Boots, unusable Framebuffer
>   issues: possibly due to the lack of double buffering and/or page
>   flipping in the bcm2708 framebuffer driver Proper libEGL library not
>   present: libraries *are* available, but those are linked against glibc
>   instead of android's bionic libc (issue filed here) UI Crashes
>
> CyanogenMOD 7.2 (based on Android 2.3): Boots, very slow, barely
>   usable.(unstable) Same problem with the hardware acceleration
>   libraries.
>
> Official Android 4.0.3 (built by Broadcom): Boots, very
>   fast with hardware acceleration, lacks AudioFlinger support. NOTE: Not
>   yet released by Broadcom! More info: Broadcom Announcement
>
> Ice Cream Sandwich (based on aosp): Very Doubtful That any Android that 
>   will be usable will ever be released.
>
> Jellybean (based on aosp): Dream on.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer to this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1299/8631) answers whether or not iOS can be put on a Raspberry Pi pretty well.

If you looking to play with [Android on Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/1700) in advance of the source code release for Android 4.0 on the Raspberry Pi, you might want to check out the community [Razdroid project](http://androidpi.wikia.com/wiki/Android_Pi_Wiki), which last month produced its first non-accelerated port of Gingerbread on top of the publicly released VideoCore binary.