# Sync music to Raspberry Pi with iTunes

Tags: usb, compatibility

Is there a way to make a Raspberry Pi behave like an iOS device? I'm looking for a way to select iTunes playlists from my main computer and have them sync with my Raspberry Pi when I connect the two via USB.

Basically I'd like to mimic the way an iPhone syncs with a Mac or PC.

Comment: @syb0rg Oh, I was a bit vague I suppose. I want to store the music on the Pi. I've seen some solutions with AirPlay, but it's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

It is not (feasibly) possible to get iTunes to recognize the Raspberry Pi when you connect it to your computer.  It might be possible with a third party application, but iTunes itself will not recognize your device, especially since it doesn't run iOS and [most likely never will](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1289/ios-on-a-raspberry-pi/1299#1299).

A more practical solution would be to stream music to your Raspberry Pi using it as an [AirPlay receiver](http://lifehacker.com/5978594/turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-an-airplay-receiver-for-streaming-music-in-your-living-room).  That way, you don't have to worry about how much space is left on your SD card because you have to much music stored on it.  I haven't tried this myself, but then (I believe) you can stream music directly from your computer (iTunes) to the Raspberry Pi itself.

I understand this may not be the answer you are looking for, but the only other solutions I see from what I have listed are manually copying playlists from your computer onto the Raspberry Pi with a USB drive.